# Сохранение результатов из БД mysql в файл с помощью php

Tags: php, mysql

Есть вот такой запрос

```
SELECT users.login,
    users.password,
    package.name_1
from 
    users
JOIN user_p_gr ON user_p_gr.login = users.login
AND time_till > 0
JOIN package ON package.pak_gr = user_p_gr.pak_gr
WHERE
    admin = 'admin_name'
```

В результате на выходе имеем

```
login password name_1
user1 password1 vcs1
user2 password2 vcs1
user1 password1 vcs2
```

Как сгенерировать с помощью php следующий конфиг файл?

```
[account]
login = 
password = 
name_1 =
```

Как пример, вот так должен выглядеть сгенерированный файл для двух пользователей

```
[account]
login = user1
password = password1
name_1 = vcs1,vcs2

[account]
login = user2
password = password2
name_1 = vcs1
```

Comment: А прямо в запросе получить требуемое представление и слить в файл (SELECT .. INTO OUTFILE) - не наш метод?

Comment: К сожалению, не хватает знаний. Можете скинуть готовый вариант? Спасибо

Comment: На этот сайт и приходят за знаниями. А за готовыми решениями - это на фриланс биржу. В первую очередь здесь нужна группировка и group_concat(). А отформатировать потом можно будет в пэхапе

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT( '[account]\nlogin = ',
                             users.login,
                             '\npassword = ',
                             users.password,
                             '\nname_1 = ',
                             package.name_1 ) SEPARATOR '\n\n' ) 
INTO OUTFILE 'c:\\output\\config.ini'
FROM users
JOIN user_p_gr ON user_p_gr.login = users.login AND time_till > 0
JOIN package ON package.pak_gr = user_p_gr.pak_gr
WHERE admin = 'admin_name'
```

Comment: Не совсем так, как нужно. Необходимо вот так: 

[account]
login = user1
password = password1
name_1 = vcs1,vcs2

А в вашем случае, получается так:

[account]
login = user1
password = password1
name_1 = vcs1

[account]
login = user1
password = password1
name_1 = vcs2

Comment: @Андрей sql не всесилен

Comment: @Андрей Ну так добавьте группировку, во проблема. Посмотрите, как из Вашего запроса получился мой, потом модифицируйте свой, чтобы получить объединённые имена, и проделайте то же преобразование в записывающий запрос.